# Is there a performant algorithm to reduce unneccessary large loop in Traces to its minimum?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, trace

Currently I am working on an algorithm to reduce the number of loop iterations in traces to what is minimum necessary.

---

More exactly, this:

```py
trace = ["a", "b", "b", "b", "c"]
```

should be reduced to:

```py
new_trace = ["a", "b", "b", "c"]
```

so that the information about "b" following "b" is not lost.

---

Another example is:

```py
trace = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "c", "d", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

should be reduced to:

```py
new_trace = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

---

I also implemented an algorithm in Python which does exactly that:

```py
def reduce_cycles(trace_variant: List[str], loop_retain_factor: int) -> List[str]:
    original_edges = list(zip(trace_variant, trace_variant[1:]))
    trace_follows_graph = Counter(original_edges)

    trace_graph = nx.DiGraph()
    trace_graph.add_edges_from(original_edges)
    trace_cycles: Generator[List[str], None, None] = nx.simple_cycles(trace_graph)

    edges_per_cycle = map(
        lambda cycle: list(zip(cycle, cycle[1:] + cycle[0:1])), trace_cycles
    )

    # reduce number of edges for cycles in trace
    for cycle_edges in edges_per_cycle:
        reduce_cycle_weight = min(itemgetter(*cycle_edges)(trace_follows_graph))

        for cycle_edge in cycle_edges:
            trace_follows_graph[cycle_edge] -= reduce_cycle_weight - loop_retain_factor

    # does not exactly work
    # especially not for examples such as trace_variant = ["a", "b", "c", "b", "c", "d", "c", "b", "e"]
    def replay_edge(acc: List[Edge], new: Edge):
        if trace_follows_graph[new] > 0:
            trace_follows_graph[new] -= 1
            return acc + [new]
        return acc

    new_trace_edges = reduce(replay_edge, original_edges, [])
    new_trace_variant = list(map(itemgetter(0), new_trace_edges))

    # add final event
    new_trace_variant.append(new_trace_edges[-1][-1])
    return new_trace_variant
```

But as you can obviously see the algorithm is not exactly performant. Especially as there normally is a huge amount of traces, meaning this function will be called for each trace. So I was wondering if there maybe already exists an algorithm which can solve this problem more efficiently or if anyone else has an idea how to improve this implementation performancewise.

I'd appreciate your help!

EDIT:
a**bcbcbc**dcbe should become a**bc**dcbe
[image]
[image]

Or if you construct a directed graph from the following trace:
abcdbcdbcdbcdbcde
[image: Trace before]

it should become
abcdbcde
[image: Trace after]

EDIT2:
I've updated the code, the description and one graph, as the comment from @kcsquared made me reevaluate this problem.

To sum up what I want is that when passing a trace to the function/algorithm it should remove all repetitions, unless removing a repetition would remove an edge in the corresponding directed graph.

- I've already figured out how to get the "repetitions"/cycles in the graph
- And I think I figured out how to update the edge weights (the edge weight of node A and B corresponds to how often B follows A in the original trace)
- I am a little bit stuck on how to get the trace afterward

Again any help appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, by 'minimum necessary' do you mean the shortest list such that `x` appears before `y` at least once in the new list if and only if `x` appeared before `y` at least once in the old list, for all vertices `x` and `y` (and with the same vertex set)?

Comment: For trace abbaa, would abab be an acceptable outcome? It's not a subsequence but would fit @kcsquared's definition (except it would be *a* shortest list fitting the criterion, not *the* shortest, as there are more than one).

Comment: Interesting subject but I think you need to more explicitly detail your needs independently of the provided code (as they may not perfectly match and because it is probably easier to understand). Besides this, it looks like what LZ compression algorithms does except you remove duplicates instead of counting them. Side question: do you want the perfect result or approximations are fine if they are fast?

Comment: Id like the perfect solution. I'll add more context and examples.

Comment: Can you give the DAG for input and output traces for the 1st example you have given after the `EDIT`.  Specifically, for `abcbcbcdcbe -> abcbcdcbe`. @Diana

Comment: The examples are good, but it's still not clear (at least to me) why the numbers are the way they are. The sentence `bc is still repeated twice to keep the local information about cb` hints that there is a definite pattern, but exactly what 'local information' you're trying to retain isn't specified in the text of the post.

Comment: The updated description clears things up— you want the shortest walk on a directed graph that still visits every edge at least once. This is the directed [route inspection problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem) and does have a fast polynomial time solution, by modeling it as a maximum flow/circulation problem.